# Can you use the new beta Adobe Flash 10.2 in Google Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome

Just wondering is it possible to use the latest Adobe Flash build (10.2) in Google Chrome?  And what are the steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers, including Chrome, can detect plugins from the ~/.mozilla/plugins folder. So you can download the flash player from Adobe and extract it there. After that, restart Chrome, type **about:plugins** in the address bar, then click the "details" button on the right to display plugin info. Scroll to Shockwave Flash and disable the versions you don't want to use.

Although Chrome lists as many flash plugins it can detect, it will use only one. The default selected plugin should be the one shipped with Chrome, so in order to use a different plugin is recommended that you disable all instances, except the one you want to use.

Download for 32bit: [http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10...](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer10_2_p2_32bit_linux_111710.tar.gz)

Download for 64bit: [http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10...](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer_square_p2_64bit_linux_092710.tar.gz)

I don't know for how long they will keep the 64bit link alive, since they recently removed the 64bit version download page.

If you are on 64bit and still has Firefox installed, you can get the 64bit preview version with my [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/161939/) extension for Firefox, which also removes conflicting plugins. It doesn't save the plugin in the .mozilla folder, but in the proper system folder, but Chrome should also detect it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!

Simply go to your `/opt/google/chrome` folder

Replace the file "libflashplayer.so" (I recommend doing a backup of that file) and your done.

I would recommend doing the same for the `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/` folder.

By the way, this combined with the 200 line kernel patch makes flash SUPER FAST even on my crappy computer!