# Getting flash 10.2 GPU acceleration working

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, flash

I'm using 32 bit ubuntu 10.10 and the latest version of the NVidia drivers for an ION GPU and have downloaded the new 10.2 flash beta.

I can confirm that in firefox I am using the beta of flash but no hardware acceleration is used for flash videos.

Do I need to install some more libraries?
Change Desktop manager?

Comment: Were you expecting flash to have gpu acceleration? AFAIK there isn't any. Can you link to any data showing they're adding GPU support?

Comment: There is support in the beta See here:  http://www.osnews.com/story/24092/Flash_Player_10_2_Beta_Delivers_Hardware_Acceleration_on_Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of research I can answer my own question. The full way to get flash using the an nvidia ion gpu on ubuntu 10.10:

Install the new flash 10.2 beta:

```
wget http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer10_2_p2_32bit_linux_111710.tar.gz
tar zxvf flashplayer10_2_p2_32bit_linux_111710.tar.gz
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/
```

You may need to also replace flash in other locations if you have installed in multiple places (try using 'locate libflashplayer.so' for a complete list)

Then for gpu support you also need (this was the bit I was missing):

```
sudo apt-get install libvdpau1
```

If you also want it working in chrome try:

- [Can you use the new beta Adobe Flash 10.2 in Google Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15819/can-you-use-the-new-beta-adobe-flash-10-2-in-google-chrome)
- http://lifehacker.com/5705588/how-to-get-the-flash-102-beta-working-in-google-chrome

To verify it is working go to a high-def you-tube video and play it. While it is playing right click and select - video info. You should see "Accelerated Video Rendering" if it has worked.

These instructions worked on my acer revo with a nvidia ion gpu.

Also on my blog with more links: http://decodify.blogspot.com/2010/12/getting-flash-102-beta-gpu-acceleration.html

Comment: Can you update your answer? By now 10.2 is in the updates repository for everyone, etc.

Comment: when you say "New beta Adobe Flash" which version number are you referring to?

Comment: Is this the whole story though? Isn't the aim to get the GPU to do the decoding as well, i.e. as well as saying "accelerated video rendering" it shouldn't say "software video decoding"? Following the process detailed above, I do see "accelerated video rendering" but still get "software video decoding" - and 100% CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line to `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` :

```
EnableLinuxHWVideoDecode=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is working, the info window should say
'accelerated' decoding instead of 'software' decoding.
Each core should drop from 100% down to 5%.

if `/etc/adobe/mms.cfg` does not exist, you must create it (plus the directory) and add that single line mentioned above.